# How can I prevent copying of flyweight objects?

Tags: c++, boost, flyweight-pattern

I'm learning using key_value flyweights and I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/flyweight.hpp>
#include <boost/flyweight/key_value.hpp>
#include <boost/flyweight/no_locking.hpp>

class Foo
{
    std::string name_;
public:
    Foo(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; std::cout << "created " << name << "\n"; }
    Foo(const Foo& f) { name_ = f.name_; std::cout << "Copied\n"; }
    ~Foo() {std::cout << "Destroyed " << name_ << "\n"; }
};

typedef boost::flyweight< boost::flyweights::key_value<std::string, Foo >,  boost::flyweights::no_locking > FooLoader;

int main()
{
{
    Foo myF = FooLoader("bar");
}
}
```

When I run it I got the follwing output:

```
created bar
Copied
Destroyed bar
Destroyed bar
```

I'd like to avoid the extra copy, since my real Foo is quite expensive to copy. This is also the primary reason I'm using a flyweight. So, is there a way to avoid the extra-copy?

Comment: If you want you can play with this code here: http://ideone.com/Xpjmk

Comment: What compiler? Could you implement a move constructor on your real Foo type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about that as compiler may optimize this, in some cases, using RVO. Use compiler options to enable such optimization wherever possible.

And especially with C++11, you should almost never worry about it, as it has introduced move-semantics which do not cost you much even if some temporary objects get created on the fly in flyweight pattern.